# How to use the converter from GCP Document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to use the converter from document ai to converter some JSONs to Document AI JSON format. Using the function described in this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-toolbox-convert-external-annotations

I used the example `config.json` from the Github page:

https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai-toolbox/blob/d29ff95742269a95e1e96e047f0fa1268457292a/samples/sample-converter-configs/Azure/invoice-config.json

And the JSON annotations from form recognizer and the PDF in the attachment (only replace `"pxl"` with `"inch"`, because this is used in the JSON annotations).

To `processor_id`, I tried an Invoice Parser processor, one new, and another that has some models that I fine-tuned, also tried the processor version ID of some trained models and also the `pretrained-invoice-v1.3-2022-07-15`.

The input bucket have this format `gs://convertion_input_test/azure_test/` and I put three files in the azure_test folder (`sample-invoice.pdf`, `sample-invoice_annotations.json` and `sample-invoice_config.json`). The output bucket is `gs://convertion_output_test/azure_test/`.

When I run the `convert_external_annotations_sample()` functions in all cases, I receive this output:

```
-------- Downloading Started --------
-------- Finished Downloading --------
-------- Converting Started --------
-------- Finished Converting --------
-------- Uploading Started --------
-------- Finished Uploading --------
-------- Schema Information --------
Unique Entity Types: []
```

And nothing is saved in the output bucket.

There are some configurations that I did wrong? I checked and the json annotation have all fields used in the config json, but I need to change something in this file?

The pdf file is like:

[sample-invoice.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hki78.png)

The `sample-invoice_config.json`:

```json
{
    "entity_object":"analyzeResult.documentResults.0.fields",
    "page": {
        "height":"analyzeResult.readResults.0.height",
        "width":"analyzeResult.readResults.0.width"
    },
    "entity": {
        "type_":"analyzeResult.documentResults.0.fields:self",
        "mention_text":"text",
        "normalized_vertices":{
            "type":"3",
            "unit":"inch",
            "base":"boundingBox",
            "x":"x",
            "y":"y"
        }
    }
}
```

And a part of the `sample-invoice_annotations.json`:

```json
{
    "status": "succeeded",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-11-06T23:32:11Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-11-06T23:32:20Z",
    "analyzeResult": {
        "version": "2.1.0",
        "readResults": [{
            "page": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "width": 8.5,
            "height": 11,
            "unit": "inch"
        }],
        "pageResults": [{
            "page": 1,
            "tables": [{
                "rows": 3,
                "columns": 4,
                "cells": [{
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "text": "QUANTITY",
                    "boundingBox": [0.4953,
                    5.7306,
                    1.8097,
                    5.7306,
                    1.7942,
                    6.0122,
                    0.4953,
                    6.0122]
                },
                {
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "columnIndex": 1,
                    "text": "DESCRIPTION",
                    "boundingBox": [1.8097,
                    5.7306,
                    5.7529,
                    5.7306,
                    5.7452,
                    6.0122,
                    1.7942,
                    6.0122]
                },
                {
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "columnIndex": 2,
                    "text": "UNIT PRICE",
                    "boundingBox": [5.7529,
                    5.7306,
                    6.8045,
                    5.7306,
                    6.8122,
                    6.0122,
                    5.7452,
                    6.0122]
                },

......
......
......

                "VendorName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "valueString": "CONTOSO LTD.",
                    "text": "CONTOSO LTD.",
                    "boundingBox": [0.5909,
                    0.6827,
                    2.3215,
                    0.6827,
                    2.3215,
                    0.8644,
                    0.5909,
                    0.8644],
                    "page": 1,
                    "confidence": 0.998
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for using the Document AI Toolbox SDK and providing feedback. I do want to note that it is in the development stage and there may be backwards-incompatible changes made before the library's `1.0.0` release.

A couple of items I noticed:

1. You don't actually need to use the Document AI [Invoice Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_invoice-processor) for the converter tool. You just need to use the [Document OCR](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/document-ocr) processor to get the OCR data.

   - The converter should still work as expected with the Invoice Parser, but if you're able to get the expected entities by sending the original documents to that processor, you can likely go without using the converter tool and just save the outputs from the processor to use in training.
   - The main purpose for this converter tool is to convert external annotation formats into the [Document](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) JSON format for importing into [Document AI Workbench](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview) to train custom processors without having to re-label manually.
2. It's difficult to tell without the full `sample-invoice_annotations.json` file, but it looks like the entities such as `"VendorName"` are nested under `pageResults` instead of `documentResults` as the `sample-invoice_config.json` is set up. Could you provide a link to the full `sample-invoice_annotations.json` file and the original PDF file you were using? (The PNG seems to be compressed quality and may not work the same)

Comment: Hello Holt, thank you for your aswer. Yesterday morning I downloaded the github code to see what was happening internally and I saw that some packages didn't exist in the current version 0.9. Getting the toolbox from:

`pip install https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai-toolbox/archive/d29ff95742269a95e1e96e047f0fa1268457292a.zip`

It works fine with the same configurations.

Comment: About the OCR processor, I saw this looking the converter.py code. Maybe is a good idea include this information in the function documentation in:

[link](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-toolbox-convert-external-annotations)

Comment: I agree that should be updated in the documentation. I will update that.

And yes, some updates have been made since the last release, but the core functionality should still work for the released version. What packages did you find were missing in the `0.9.0` release?

Comment: I remember the `google.cloud.documentai_toolbox.converters.config.block`, because it was the first. Unfortunately I didn't pay attention to the other packages. This occured when I tried to run the current `converter.py` with the last pip package release installed (`0.9.0`).

Comment: Yes, I did do a refactoring that moved stuff around and changed some names (shouldn't impact any functionality, I thought). But I made a new release `0.9.1` from the latest state of the repo. Try upgrading and running this again.